# IBOutlet is not initialized

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iboutlet

there is something strange with xcode. Suddenly the ordinary flow is broken. To check it I've created a new project with just two viewControllers. First (named ViewController) contains only one button to open the second (named NewViewController) controller, which contains the only UILabel.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "Show New View" {
            guard let newVC = segue.destination as? NewViewController else { return }

            newVC.passedText = "some abstract text"
        }
    }
}

import UIKit

class NewViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

    var passedText: String? {
        didSet {
            guard let text = passedText else { return }

            myLabel.text = text
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

[the main.storyboard looks so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLcF5.png)

[IBOutlet is well connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvw1L.png)

[But the debugger shows what the UILabel is nil](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJdL3.png)

What I've made wrong?

Comment: This is normal. The view is not yet loaded in `prepareForSegue` So the outlets are not set. You should conditionally unwrap the outlet in your setter and you need to establish the initial state of your views in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`

Comment: yes, I've got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, nothing has "broken". You're the one who is doing it wrong. At the time you are calling `newVC.passedText = "some abstract text"`, `newVC` has not yet loaded its view and its outlets are still `nil`. So the call to set `myLabel.text` is happening at time when the outlet is indeed still `nil`.

Your mistake is that you are trying to configure `myLabel` too soon. Store the value in `newVC`, yes. But as for setting `myLabel.text`, wait until `viewDidLoad`, when the view and outlets are working.

The correct pattern, therefore, looks like this:

```
var passedText: String? {
    didSet {
        guard let text = passedText else { return }
        myLabel?.text = text
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    guard let text = passedText else { return }
    myLabel?.text = text
}
```

Now your code does the right thing regardless of *when* `passedText` is set in relation to `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Yes, you're correct! I've checked my previous and worked well code. I've checked the passed variables in viewDidLoad() or viewWillAppear(). So, previously it works and now this is my mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the custom class `NewViewController` in the identity inspector of the view controller in the storyboard. Maybe you forgot to do that?

Comment: Yes, but apparently it was not the problem ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem when I was initializing my UIViewController from the SceneDelegate, if I initialize my UIView controller like this:

```
window = UIWindow(windowScene: winScene)
let navigationController = UINavigationController()
        navigationController.pushViewController(
            MyViewController(), animated: false)
window?.rootViewController = navigationController
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

The  **@IBOutlet var** would be nil in the **viewDidLoad** function, but if I initialize it using storyboard like this:

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
let initViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController") as UIViewController
window = UIWindow(windowScene: winScene)
let navigationController = UINavigationController()
navigationController.pushViewController(
            initViewController, animated: false)
window?.rootViewController = navigationController
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Then all **@IBOutlet var** would be initialized in the **viewDidLoad** function.